# How to get all size attributes from html code using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this code:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT SIZE="9" COLOR="#2C363D" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">A draft Ad for YAPAR_3743-Tv2 has been produced and is ready for your review and approval. </FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT SIZE="9" COLOR="#2C363D" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"> </FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT SIZE="9" COLOR="#2C363D" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Thank You, </FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT SIZE="9" COLOR="#2C363D" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecteturAdipiscingElitNullamEgetMaurisQuam EnergisticallyUnleashProactiveIdeasWhereasHigh-PayoffTechnologies</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

I need to get all size attributes with value, for example SIZE="9".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply this expression:

```
(SIZE="\d+")
```

If you need to also accept units, like px or %:

```
(SIZE="\d+(px|%)?")
```

Accept extra spaces in between the =

```
(SIZE\s*=\s*"\d+(px|%)?")
```

Take also into account if there are upper and lower cases (run the regex wtih case insensitive option).